# Useless use of log in void context

Tags: perl

What is wrong with this code?

I get an error: `Useless use of log in void context at ./test.pl line 12.`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

log();

sub log {
    print "Test";
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[log](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/log.html) is a built-in Perl function.  One way to solve this is to rename your sub:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

mylog();

sub mylog {
    print "Test";
    return;
}
```

Comment: @tomsk Additionally, if you had defined `log` before calling it, you would have had a warning `Ambiguous call resolved as CORE::log()`. So calling `main::log();` will call the `log` you defined (you probably shouldn't do this though)

Comment: Note that `perlcritic` generates a more meaningful warning message for the OP: `Subroutine name is a homonym for builtin function log at line...`

Comment: You can read about log() with `perldoc -f log` or at http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/log.html

Comment: The alternative is `use subs qw( log );`